# Rebuild text sequence from base and diff

Tags: diff

I have two text sequences in memory and run a diff on them. Later I want to take the base sequence and the diff and reconstitute the second sequence. A Python solution would be perfect but a command line utility would be OK too. The solution must work on Windows, Linux and MacOS. Needs to be efficient because it will be carried out millions of times. My Internet searches have not turned up a good answer.

Comment: Have you considered `diff` and `patch`?  I'm sure Windows has native versions, but they'll definitely run in cygwin.

Comment: I have changed my mind about using OS utilities because of the overhead. I would need to invoke them 5-50 million times per run which becomes prohibitive.